# What is Installer project in abp framework module template?

Tags: abp

In abp framework module template solution, there is a project named [ProjectName].Installer. Also in built in modules same project exists. What is it and What is used for?
I noticed that there is a file [ProjectName].abpmdl.json that contains all *.abppkg.json addresses in solution. I think it should do some thing with that.

Comment: this is for a new project called ABP Studio. You cannot directly use it.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu is there a way we could create a custom module, and install it using abp cli `abp add-module Custom.Mod`

Comment: Currently not possible installing 3rd party modules by ABP CLI